# How to persist a Map<String, List<Object>> in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, h2

I've got a `Map` containing `MyObject` instances. The `MyObject` class uses JPA to persist its fields:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private Map<String, MyObject> results = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
```

We changed the *value stored by* the `Map` to a `List`:

```
private Map<String, List<MyObject>> results = new HashMap<String, List<MyObject>>();
```

But upon launching we receive a stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.me.myapp.MyObject.results[java.util.List]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1150)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:680)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder$1.secondPass(MapBinder.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1221)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:673)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    ... 30 more
```

Does Hibernate not support persisting a `Map` containing (as values) `List` types? Or are my annotations incorrect? I haven't found this particular configuration in any of the documentation or examples.

Comment: Is MyObject a JPA mapped class?

Comment: @ToddMurray: It must be, or else the OP wouldn't be getting an error message about how the `MyObject.results` field is annotated as `@OneToMany`.

Comment: Yep, instances of MyObject are currently being stored in Hibernate. But now instead of storing a Map with String->MyObject, the Map should instead be String->List<MyObject>

Comment: Consider improving your domain objects. Do you really want to store a List<MyObject>? Would your system improve if you have a separate class that holds onto a List<MyObject> and then store THAT one in the map?

Comment: @Jochen: Exactly my point.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think this is a good use of Hibernate.  There's *no* abstraction here.  It would make sense if you had a model object with a one-to-many relation expressed as a child List as a data member in the parent.

My advice?  Don't use Hibernate.  Use straight JDBC, Spring's JDBC template, or something like iBatis.

ORM stands for "Object Relational Mapping".  You have tables, so you've got the relational part.  You've got data that you can assign to columns in tables.

But it sounds to me like you've got no Objects.  So why use Hibernate?

Comment: We have a number of other relationships stored in Hibernate. We're currently migrating between two data models, so we're experimenting to determine just how Hibernate structures the database, and what we need to include in our SQL/migration scripts to accommodate the changes. These classes/relationships aren't final, but thanks for the tips. :)

Comment: Maybe you can mix and match.  Your persistence tier need not be all one technology.  Use what makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The objects  stored in the map must be the target object of the oneToMany association (always mapped). You can't store arbitrary objects or collections there.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like the issue can be alleviated through some of the other commented suggestions - primarily encapsulating the List into another class, and storing that class as the value in the Map.