# How do I persist a Map<String, List<String>>?

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to persist a `Map<String, List<String>>` and I have no idea how to do so.

So far I have tried the following, without success:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  ...

  @ElementCollection
  private Map<String, List<String>> errors;

  //getters & setters
}
```

Is there a correct way to do it using String or do I have to create another entity to map it to?

Edit: I am using Hibernate

Thanks.

Comment: I can't help you on that as i am not good on that topic, but i think you may better specify if you are using jpa / hibernate / eclipselink... or whatever you are using for data persistence either in the body of your question and in tags, that will get more attention to your question

Comment: Did you check suggested related questions? Like this one [How to persist a Map<String, List<Object>> in Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283966/how-to-persist-a-mapstring-listobject-in-hibernate)?

Answer (score 0):

Not really the solution I was hoping for, but due to simplicity I removed the list from the Map and persisted the list as a String, using ";" to break the elements. Afterwards I just split it back to a list.

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  ...

  @ElementCollection
  private Map<String, String> errors;

  //getters & setters
}
```